# AGND VS DGND on PCB?

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, pcb-design

Could someone please tell me the difference between analog ground and digital ground on pcb?

It would be easier if you explained it with a example!

Comment: Where are you looking, it really depends on the schematic and the designer, show and example.

Comment: What did you find searching on internet or this site so far? Could you be more specific what you don't understand?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between different types of GND](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/140293/what-is-the-difference-between-different-types-of-gnd)

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Source: [Where to put regulator when separating analog and digital grounds?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/325810/where-to-put-regulator-when-separating-analog-and-digital-grounds)

Some designers like to separate digital and analog sections. There are some parts that even have an analog ground and digital ground. This is to prevent return currents from devices in the digital section creating 'ground bounce' on sensitive devices in the analog section.

In a schematic, usually the grounds will be indicated with different symbols and net names on the schematic, and a *net tie* is used to join them together.
[image]
[KiCAD 5 --- what is the significance of the various GND symbols?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/392911/kicad-5-what-is-the-significance-of-the-various-gnd-symbols)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at schematic for a digital cameras (from TI) and found that there are different grounding. Will check it later.